# Cannot find symbol variable inside values-es folder

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use a string-array variable that I created in a folder called values-es, however when I try to call it it says `cannot find symbol variable myStrings2`. I am not sure why it doesn't work because all I did was copy everything from my `strings.xml` to my `strings.xml (es)` version and changed the array name.

[image]

I am trying to use `myStrings` and `myStrings2` from the xml files so depending on what the system language is, it will display the appropriate language

I used them in two different files, `ColorAdapter` (in the getElementFromColors function) and `PaletteActivity` (inside onCreate() ) and received the error message on both files

**ColorAdapter**

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ColorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Integer> colors;
    Context context;

    public ColorAdapter(Context context){

        this.context=context;
        colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int retrieve []=context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.myColors);
        for(int i:retrieve)
        {
            colors.add(i);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return colors.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int args) {
        return colors.get(args);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int args) {
        return args;
    }

    public String getElementFromColors(int position){
        String CurrentLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        if(CurrentLang=="es"){
            String retrieve[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myStrings2);
            return retrieve[position];
        }else{
            String retrieve[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myStrings);
            return retrieve[position];
        }


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
        TextView txv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        txv.setBackgroundColor(colors.get(position));
        txv.setText(getElementFromColors(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**PaletteActivity**

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.session.PlaybackState;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;


public class PaletteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String CurrentLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        setTitle("Palette Activity");
        final Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.myColors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        if(CurrentLang=="es"){
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringNames = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.myStrings2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            stringNames.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        }else{
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringNames = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.myStrings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            stringNames.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        }


        spinner.setAdapter(new ColorAdapter(this));

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position == 0){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                }
                else if(position == 1){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                    Intent i = new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",1);
                    PaletteActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                }else if(position == 2){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                    Intent i = new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",2);
                    PaletteActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                }else if(position == 3){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                    Intent i = new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",3);
                    PaletteActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                }else if(position == 4){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                    Intent i = new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",4);
                    PaletteActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                }else if(position == 5){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                    Intent i = new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",5);
                    PaletteActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                }else if(position == 6){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                    Intent i = new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",6);
                    PaletteActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                }else if(position == 7){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                    Intent i = new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",7);
                    PaletteActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                }else if(position == 8){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                    Intent i = new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",8);
                    PaletteActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                }else if(position == 9){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                    Intent i = new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",9);
                    PaletteActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                }else if(position == 10){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                    Intent i = new Intent(PaletteActivity.this, CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",10);
                    PaletteActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**CanvasActivity**

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CanvasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_canvas);

        String CurrentLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        TextView text = findViewById(R.id.newColor);

        final View newBackground;
        newBackground = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());


        Intent i = getIntent();
         int pos = i.getIntExtra("position",0);


                if(pos == 1){
                    newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.silver);
                    if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                        text.setText("Plata");
                    }
                    else{
                        text.setText("Silver");
                    }

                }else if(pos == 2){
                    newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.pink);
                    if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                        text.setText("Rosado");
                    }
                    else{
                        text.setText("Pink");
                    }
                }else if(pos == 3){
                    newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
                    if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                        text.setText("Rojo");
                    }
                    else{
                        text.setText("Red");
                    }
                }else if(pos == 4){
                    newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
                    if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                        text.setText("Naranja");
                    }
                    else{
                        text.setText("Orange");
                    }
                }else if(pos == 5){
                    newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
                    if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                        text.setText("Amarillo");
                    }
                    else{
                        text.setText("Yellow");
                    }
                }else if(pos == 6){
                    newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
                    if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                        text.setText("Verde");
                    }
                    else{
                        text.setText("Green");
                    }
                }else if(pos == 7){
                    newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
                    if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                        text.setText("Azul");
                    }
                    else{
                        text.setText("Blue");
                    }
                }else if(pos == 8){
                    newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.indigo);
                    if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                        text.setText("índigo");
                    }
                    else{
                        text.setText("Indigo");
                    }
                }else if(pos == 9){
                    newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.violet);
                    if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                        text.setText("Violeta");
                    }
                    else{
                        text.setText("Violet");
                    }
                }else if(pos == 10){
                    newBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.color.brown);
                    if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                        text.setText("Marrón");
                    }
                    else{
                        text.setText("Brown");
                    }
                }
        }


}
```

**strings.xml from values-es folder**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Color Activity</string>
    <string name="Color">Color</string>
    <string-array name="myStrings2">
            <item>Selecciona un color</item>
            <item>Plata</item>
            <item>Rosado</item>
            <item>Rojo</item>
            <item>Naranja</item>
            <item>Amarillo</item>
            <item>Verde</item>
            <item>Azul</item>
            <item>Índigo</item>
            <item>Violeta</item>
            <item>Marrón</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Color Activity</string>
    <string name="Color">Color</string>
    <string-array name="myStrings">
        <item>Select a color</item>
        <item>Silver</item>
        <item>Pink</item>
        <item>Red</item>
        <item>Orange</item>
        <item>Yellow</item>
        <item>Green</item>
        <item>Blue</item>
        <item>Indigo</item>
        <item>Violet</item>
        <item>Brown</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>


    <color name="silver" type="color">#c0c0c0</color>
    <color name="pink" type="color">#ffc0cb</color>
    <color name="red" type="color">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="orange" type="color">#ffa500</color>
    <color name="yellow" type="color">#ffff00</color>
    <color name="green" type="color">#00ff00</color>
    <color name="blue" type="color">#0000ff</color>
    <color name="indigo" type="color">#4b0082</color>
    <color name="violet" type="color">#7f00ff</color>
    <color name="brown" type="color">#654321</color>
    <color name="white" type="color">#FFFFFF</color>
    <integer-array name="myColors">
        <item>@color/white</item>
        <item>@color/silver</item>
        <item>@color/pink</item>
        <item>@color/red</item>
        <item>@color/orange</item>
        <item>@color/yellow</item>
        <item>@color/green</item>
        <item>@color/blue</item>
        <item>@color/indigo</item>
        <item>@color/violet</item>
        <item>@color/brown</item>
    </integer-array>



</resources>
```

**FIXED:**

Solved by doing the following:

1.Changed project mode to Android mode

2.Right click on values folder

3.Named the file called strings

4.Select Locale as qualifier

5.Choose the language

6.Click ok

7.Enter whatever in the translation xml

It should put both strings.xml files within a strings folder. I found it to work when the strings.xml (es) was not in a separate folder compared to strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Change it

```
 if(CurrentLang=="es")
```

To it

```
 if(CurrentLang.equals("es"))
```

Comment: Did you relaunch your app ?

Note : you don't need to separate out two variables string-array.
Set name of string resource in " strings.xml from values-es folder " same string.xml in values folder.
Android system will auto detect which language device using and use the right resource, whenever you change the language in settings.

Comment: No errors this time, but the dropdown spinner doesn't change the text from english to spanish when I change it on the system settings

Comment: I just created simple application support english and spain for textview , check this you will know how to update your app : 
https://github.com/thanhlv93/MultipleLanguageTest